# Select an entire row from a table and store the entire row in a CLOB field in another table DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have two tables - EMPLOYEE_TABLE and CLOB_TABLE. I wish to get a row from EMPLOYEE_TABLE and store it in a column of CLOB type in CLOB_TABLE.
Is it possible to create a procedure that selects an entire row from a table (EMPLOYEE_TABLE) based on its primary key value and store the resulting row inside another table's(CLOB_TABLE) CLOB field?

Comment: you can concatinate all the rows into one column and insert it into a clob field if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [XMLROW scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmlrow).

```
INSERT INTO CLOB_TABLE (PK, CLOB_DOC)
SELECT PK, XMLSERIALIZE (XMLROW (COL1, ..., COLN) AS CLOB (100K))
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
```

The size of CLOB in XMLSERIALIZE should match the size of the `CLOB_DOC` column.
[XMLTABLE table function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmltable) can be used to parse `CLOB_DOC` values.